# How to set the proxy variable in bash?

Tags: bash, proxy, sonoma

How to set the proxy variable in bash in macOS?
I cannot install Homebrew, it gives the following error:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445489/performing-http-requests-with-curl-using-proxy). The question is for Linux, but I don't think that the MacOS `curl` is so different that it would not apply there as well.